# Multiple ng-repeat on single element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is this possible to achieve a code like this:-

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataArray,value in valueArray">
       {{data}} {{value}}
 </tr>
```

I am having two arrays I want to show them in single row.
PS: I am not asking for syntax. I am looking for logic to achieve this

Thanks

Like :- "http://jsfiddle.net/6ob5bkcx/1/"

Comment: Even with the jsFiddle, I'm really not clear on what the required output is in this situation. Can you post (here, not in jsFiddle) some example output HTML and some example input arrays?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be doing this in the controller, not in the view. Map the dataValues into a key/value pair object and reference the values array using an index. This assumes that each data key has a corresponding value key.

**Controller:**

```
var dataArray = [];
var valueArray = [];
this.repeatData = dataArray.map(function(value, index) {
    return {
        data: value,
        value: valueArray[index]
    }
});
```

**View:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in repeatData">
    {{data.data}} {{data.value}}
</tr>
```

Comment: What happens when the size of arrays are different?

Comment: I recommend putting the data in an object. Like :  this.obj = [{data: 'a', value :true}, {data: 'b', value:true}];

Answer (score 3):

Does this suits your need

http://jsfiddle.net/jmo65wyn/

Your data, value array as object array

```
 this.obj = [{data: 'a', value :true}, {data: 'b', value:true}];
```

And you loop like this

```
 <div ng:repeat="o in obj">
       {{o.data}} and {{o.value}} 
         <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.value">
    </div>
```

Comment: I m asking for two different arrays not the single array with multple objects :-)

Comment: you can always combine them in to one dictionary(in your controller). Any ways your above link is not working

Answer (score 2):

Angular ng-repeat does not support it but still you can write your own custom directive according to your requirements.

### Update Section

```
var traverseCollection = angular.module("CollectionTraverse", []);

traverseCollection.directive("repeatCollection", function(){

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            model: "="
        },
        controller: controller: function($scope) {
            var collectionList = $scope.model;

            angular.forEach(collectionList, function(obj, index) {
                angular.forEach(obj, function(data, index) {

                });
            });
        }
    }
});

Your scope should contains the list of your collection objects : $scope.collectionList = [dataArray, valueArray];

Usage in HTML:
-------------------------------------------
<div repeat_collection model="collectionList"></div>
```

This directive will be generic to traverse list of collections and yes in the above code there can be some syntactical errors because i did not run it. Its your luck.

Comment: So is there any alternative for that..??

Comment: No you will have to write custom directive as per your need, Angular allows you to do so.

Comment: See the Update Section of the above code.It will help you to handle your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have, for any reason, two arrays with the same length and where their contents are corresponding (`array1[0]` correspond to `array2[0]`, ..., `array1[n]` correspond to `array2[n]`), you can use AngularJS's [`track by`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) (which was introduced for the 1st time in the version [1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#114-quantum-manipulation-2013-04-03)) like this for example :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Bill','Billa','Billy']; ages=['10', '20', '30']">
  <tr ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
    <td>{{ name }} is {{ ages[$index] }} years old.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score -1):

if you want something like a list with two or more items in the same row:

in html file:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<i class="material-icons">{{navItem[1]}}</i>{{navItem[0]}}</li>
```

in js file:

```
$scope.items = [
    ["Home", "home"],
    ["Favorite", "favorite"]
]
```