# created only one input for multiple values in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looping through JSON for user id's & want to assign all the user id from json to one html field. However ng-repeat creates a new input tag for each value. Here is the fiddle. http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Ly6q14c/ 
Is there a way I can loop through all userIds & assign them in one input element?

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[
  {
    'userId': '15',
    'mgId': '1',
    'mgName': 'Oracle'
  },
  {
    'userId': '16',
    'mgId': '2',
    'mgName': 'SunCorp'
  }
]">
<p>Looping with objects:</p>
  <div ng-repeat="x in names">
  <input ng-model="x.userId"></input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **assign them in one input element?** . Why you did't like to use `select` tag?

Comment: quick thought, create a method inside a controller that joins the ids, and then call the method from the input.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

**Controller:**

```
$scope.names = [
    {
      'userId': '15',
      'mgId': '1',
      'mgName': 'Oracle'
    },
    {
      'userId': '16',
      'mgId': '2',
      'mgName': 'SunCorp'
    }
  ]

  $scope.allIds = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.names, function(name) {
    $scope.allIds.push(name.userId);
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="allIds"></input>
```

Also you can check in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuhde6th/1/)

Comment: It's good. But he's did't use controller, then how can he will complete this? –

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thanks for your comment, have added a fiddle example to show the same. I feel controller would be needed  in MVC model over a period of time, thus  included the controller in my answer.

Comment: I need to do it without using a controller. I have other code wrapped around it, manipulating all those ids using controller will make it more complicated. but your idea works absolutely fine. Any chance of achieving this without controller?

Comment: Also I need to use if condition, in this example, if mg-id is 1 then only add userId to the list, is that possible on html side without using controller?

Comment: Angular ng-repeat does not support it but you can write your own custom directive. 
Please see the answer posted by Suneet Bansal in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901793/multiple-ng-repeat-on-single-element