# How to reduce HTML header display of Firebase Data from AngularJS Call?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that contains courses which have courseIDs, sections, etc. Each entry for course can have 1 or more sections. There can be duplicate courses of the same courseID with different sections (shown below).

[image: Firebase Structure]

Basically, I want to *reduce the redundancy* when displaying in HTML by combining the like courses to not repeat the headers (courseID).

**Currently**:
[image: Separated]

**What I want**:
[image: Together]

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="course in courses | orderBy:'+courseID'">
    ...
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{course.courseID}}</h3>
    ...
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped sections-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>End</th>
        <th>Days</th>
        <th>Grad TAs</th>
        <th>Undergrad TAs</th>
        <th>Undergrad LAs</th>
        <th>Candidates</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="section in course.sections">
        <td>{{section.sectionID}}</td>
        <td>{{section.instructor}}</td>
        <td>{{section.startTime}}</td>
        <td>{{section.endTime}}</td>
        <td>{{prettifyDays(section.days)}}</td>
        <td>{{section.gradTAsNeeded}}</td>
        <td>{{section.undergradTAsNeeded}}</td>
        <td>{{section.undergradLAsNeeded}}</td>
        <td ng-init="sec = section">
     ...
```

**Angular**

```
...
$scope.courses = [];
...
firebaseService.getCourses(function(courses) {
    $scope.courses = courses;
    console.log(courses);
    $scope.$apply();
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I cannot link to the actual running site as it contains confidential student data so if there's anything else needed please let me know.

Comment: You should be able to combine `course in courses` and `section in course.sections` on the controller into a key/value pair -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901793/multiple-ng-repeat-on-single-element

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hmm, I'm trying to think how to make that work. How would I loop through the key/value pairs without duplicating the header each time? Each course is referenced later on so I need to be able to continue referencing each entry of course. What I want here is just for the purposes of display.

Comment: You're currently looping through `course in courses` in an `ng-repeat` in the parent DIV at the moment. This also includes the header row in the repeat. Essentially, you're looking for a way to combine the 'logic' behind `courses` and `sections` in the controller, so that you can use a **single** `ng-repeat` on your `<tr>` (where you currently repeat `section in course.sections`). Unfortunately, I can't quite that of the exact logic you would need to combine, but it would be use a map: `.map(function(value, index) {})`, and is certainly how you need to approach this problem :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Can I create a secondary array for display and while I loop through that I increment the position in the original array by 1 to be used to reference later on? ALSO Is it possible to loop based on numerical indexes (i=0;i<length;i++) then call whichever index of whichever array needed?