# Multiple ng-repeat in the same div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I almost found my answer here ([Multiple ng-repeat on single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901793/multiple-ng-repeat-on-single-element)), I just need a little help.

I'm trying to display multiples values in the same div using ng-repeat. I followed what was answered in the link above, though I don't know what to put in $scope.
So far nothing displays.

Here is my JS:

```
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`trips/${userid}/trips`).once('value') 


.then(photosSnap => {
    var photosObj = photosSnap.val();
    var tripName = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].name);
    var tripPhotoUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].photourl);

 this.repeatData = tripName.map(function(value, index) {
return {
    data: value,
    value: tripPhotoUrl[index]
}
});

    $scope.repeatData = data;
    $scope.repeatData = value;

    $scope.$apply();

    console.log($scope);
}).catch(err => alert(err));

     });
```

And my HTML:

```
 <div class="main" ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div id="usertripinfo" ng-repeat="data in repeatData" style="background-image: url({{data.value}}); height: 300px; width: 600px;">

     {{data.data}}

    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: You cannot use style="background-image: url({{data.value}}); like this in ur view, use ng-class instead and what don't u assign the map directly to $scope instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assigning the result to `$scope.repeatData` makes it available in the html file as `repeatData`, try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`trips/${userid}/trips`).once('value')


      .then(photosSnap => {
        var photosObj = photosSnap.val();
        var tripName = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].name);
        var tripPhotoUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].photourl);

        $scope.repeatData = tripName.map(function (value, index) {
          return {
            data: value,
            value: tripPhotoUrl[index]
          }
        });
      }).catch(err => alert(err));
  });
```

Comment: Just one more question, how can I modify it to add one or more variables in the same scope ?

Comment: simply add your variable name as a key in $scope, e.g `$scope.myVariable = 5` will make `myVariable` available in the html with a value of 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $scope.repeatData = data;
   $scope.repeatData = value;
```

I think by doing this **repeatData** is override by value. that's why you can not get value properly.

but if you want both **data** as well as **value** than you can assign in object using different key.