# Display edited data as well as previous data in same row of a table in angularJS 1x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.newField = [];
  $scope.editing = false;

  $scope.data = [{
    "supplier_name": "ABC",
    "first_name": "example",
    "last_name": "test",
    "email": "example@abc.com",
    "telephone_number": "919-575-5506"
  }, {
    "supplier_name": "XYZ",
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "example",
    "email": "example@abc.com",
    "telephone_number": "919-575-5506"
  }]
  $scope.editData = function(field) {
    $scope.editing = $scope.data.indexOf(field);
    $scope.newField[$scope.editing] = angular.copy(field);
    console.log($scope.data.indexOf(field));
  }

  $scope.saveData = function(index) {
    $scope.data[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(index) {
    $scope.data[index] = $scope.newField[index];
    $scope.editing = false;
  };

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table id="supplierTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="supplier_name">Supplier Name</th>
          <th id="first_name">First Name</th>
          <th id="last_name"> Last Name</th>
          <th id="email">Email</th>
          <th id="telephone_number">phone</th>
          <th>Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr name="supplierTable" data-ng-repeat="supplier in data">
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="editMode">{{supplier.supplier_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="editMode"><input type="text" name="supplier_name" ng-model="supplier.supplier_name" readonly />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="editMode">{{supplier.first_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="editMode"><input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="supplier.first_name" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="editMode">{{supplier.last_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="editMode"><input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="supplier.last_name" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="editMode">{{supplier.email}}</div>
            <div ng-show="editMode"><input type="email" name="email" size="30" ng-model="supplier.email" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="editMode">{{supplier.telephone_number}}</div>
            <div ng-show="editMode"><input type="tel" ng-model="supplier.telephone_number" required pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true; editData(supplier)">Edit</button>
            <button ng-disabled="supplierTable.$invalid" ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false;">
                        Save</button>
            <button ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; cancel($index)">Cancel</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </div>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to display the result of saved data and the edited data in the same row. I have achieved the inline edit and save functionality. Now what I am trying to do is relate my previous entry and new data stored in  $scope.newField = []; and display that in the same row after hitting the save button. 
I have tried [this kind of approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901793/multiple-ng-repeat-on-single-element) but my problem is that initially $scope.newField = [] is empty and once I make changes I will have data in  $scope.newField = [];. any suggestion on how can I achieve this.

Comment: do you want to show the old values under the new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues. For example:

1. Variable `$scope.editing` is Boolean, but you write `$scope.editing = $scope.data.indexOf(field)`
2. You do not run function `saveData` nowhere

I changed your code. You can test it on field `First Name` only.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  previousDataBuffer = {}
  editingIndex = null;

  $scope.data = [{
    "supplier_name": "ABC",
    "first_name": "example",
    "last_name": "test",
    "email": "example@abc.com",
    "telephone_number": "919-575-5506"
  }, {
    "supplier_name": "XYZ",
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "example",
    "email": "example@abc.com",
    "telephone_number": "919-575-5506"
  }];
   
  $scope.previousData = new Array($scope.data.length);

  $scope.editData = function(index) {
    previousDataBuffer = angular.copy($scope.data[index]);
    editingIndex = index;
  }

  $scope.saveData = function(index) {
    $scope.previousData[index] = previousDataBuffer;
    editingIndex = null;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(index) {
    $scope.data[index] = angular.copy(previousDataBuffer);
    editingIndex = null;
  };

  $scope.isEditingRow = function(index) {
    return index === editingIndex;
  };
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table id="supplierTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="supplier_name">Supplier Name</th>
          <th id="first_name">First Name</th>
          <th id="last_name"> Last Name</th>
          <th id="email">Email</th>
          <th id="telephone_number">phone</th>
          <th>Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr name="supplierTable" data-ng-repeat="supplier in data">
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)">{{supplier.supplier_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="isEditingRow($index)"><input type="text" name="supplier_name" ng-model="supplier.supplier_name" readonly />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)">
<span ng-if="previousData[$index].first_name && previousData[$index].first_name != supplier.first_name">{{previousData[$index].first_name}} / </span>
{{supplier.first_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="isEditingRow($index)"><input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="supplier.first_name" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)">{{supplier.last_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="isEditingRow($index)"><input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="supplier.last_name" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)">{{supplier.email}}</div>
            <div ng-show="isEditingRow($index)"><input type="email" name="email" size="30" ng-model="supplier.email" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)">{{supplier.telephone_number}}</div>
            <div ng-show="isEditingRow($index)"><input type="tel" ng-model="supplier.telephone_number" required pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button ng-hide="isEditingRow($index)" data-ng-click="editData($index)">Edit</button>
            <button ng-disabled="supplierTable.$invalid" ng-show="isEditingRow($index)" data-ng-click="saveData($index)">
                        Save</button>
            <button ng-show="isEditingRow($index)" data-ng-click="cancel($index)">Cancel</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </div>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it worked fine, However there is a small change in cancel to work so I made that change to display the previous value. Now when I hit edit button it shows edit for all the rows although I am passing index of specific row.

Comment: If we have an entry "processed ": "yes " (No or In-process) in data[]. can we hide the edit button for no and in process based on that value in database? and also  remove previous data entry(display only new data) if processed state is yes?

Comment: will it be a good idea to have an id field in data[{....}] and relate new and old data based on that id rather than  relying on index  because we are storing data in two different array and ultimately it will go to two different database tables. please excuse me if I am asking any dumb question as I am beginner in this field.

Comment: Chandra, designing a database is a complicated thing and you need to know all the technical requirements to make the right architecture. 
You can write everything in one collection `[ { data: { key: value}, logs: [ { key: value} ]} ]`, but it's not good idea, because at some moment you will need clean data without logs.
And the collection will become too big to manage it. Data and logs are always stored separately.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is to display values which are in data[{....}] coming from a database  with an ID, processed status and other field. now when a user make an edit, new values goes to other temp table and id will remain same with new values and status changes to in process so no editing is allowed during that stage.once its processed state changes to yes, I will have only one entry displayed to the user and the new data is stored in the main table in DB and temp table(which is previousData[{...}] rightNow) is again empty .

Comment: Chandra, if you need to save the previous values and display it after page reloading - you need add new fields to DB, the easiest way - duplicate current fields i.e. `first_name, prev_first_name, last_name, prev_last_name` etc. BUT, usually make synchronization on the Back End with a separate table. So when you save data, Back End gets previous data from DB table and then saves it to another table, and then saves new data to main table.